# Why some browsers display images while other doesn't ? Rails 4

Tags: image, browser, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

My problem is that images on my page (iutm.pl) are displaying properly for instance in Firefox (then I assume there is nothing wrong with my code), but on WebKit or Blink browsers (such as Chrome or Opera) they doesn't.

Maybe it is Paperclip fault which I use to store images (there is need to keep relation between database and images) cause images stored explicitly in assets display properly.
Anyway, i have no idea why everything works in Gecko, but not with other engines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap overrides width and height of your images. The simplest solution is to add width and height attributes to existing styles where you define border for images. This code does the trick.

```
.event_frame .frame-top .frame-img img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #b2b2b2;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Yep. That's solution. ;) Thanks a lot.